# bad_variant_access not working

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I am trying to get a `std::bad_variant_access` exception when the variant is not in the list .But the below code doesn't work it returns a implicit converted ASCII int value

what changes should I do that variant is strict on type selection

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
using namespace std;

struct printer
{
    void operator()(int x) {
        cout << x << "i"<<endl;

    }
    void operator()(float x) {
        cout << x << "f"<<endl;
    }
    void operator()(double x)
    {
        cout << x << "d" << endl;;
    }
};
int main() {

    using my_variant = std::variant<int, float, double>;
    my_variant v0('c');

    try {
        std::visit(printer{}, v0);
        }

    catch(const std::bad_variant_access& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 99i

Whereas I was expecting to get `std::bad_variant_access` exception

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6b7c0fe8062c38d3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::visit` will only trigger a `bad_variant_access` exception if the variant is [valueless_by_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/valueless_by_exception) (C++17, see N4659 23.7.3.5 [variant.status] )

What this means is that if you tried to set a variant value in a fashion that throws an exception, the variant is left in a "valueless" state, so visitation is not permitted.

To trigger it, we can change the code like so:

```
struct S{

    operator int() const{throw 42;}
};

struct printer{//as before};

int main() {
    using my_variant = std::variant<int, float, double>;
    my_variant v0{'c'};

    try{
       v0.emplace<0>(S());
    }catch(...){}

    try {
        std::visit(printer{}, v0);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_variant_access& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ly1usQNIFBMolR20)

[Frank already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760905/27678) why you could construct your variant in the first place using a `char` (construction chosen via overload).

You can not trigger a `bad_variant_access` by attempting to first construct a variant in a fashion that will throw because [variant.ctor] dictates that the constructor will rethrow that exception (in this case `int`).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant):

That constructor of variant does the following:

> Constructs a variant holding the alternative type T_j **that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression F(std::forward(t)) if there was an overload of imaginary function F(T_i) for every T_i from Types...** in scope at the same time. [...]

I.e. std::variant will get the first type that is constructible from the passed argument. In this case, `int` is constructible from a `char`, so the variant gets assigned as such.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it  and be more strict?

Comment: one my client code  is doing that  because of  which the whole code breaks

Comment: It should be possible to create a wrapper around `std::variant` that has more stringent construction rules, but I wouldn't recommend going down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @HariomSingh I'm not sure if you can because `char` implicitly becomes an `int`.  If you used custom types that did not allow this implicit conversion it should work.

Comment: @ NathanOliver I was thinking of a constructor (or constructing method) that identifies the matching index by using `std::is_same`. This would be annoyingly strict, but should work.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you are right , I will have to go on that path . I was looking for any quick workaround if any available

Comment: Can I try something with std::visit?

Comment: @Hariom Singh no, because your problem occurs at assignment time. It's too late by the time you call `visit()`, the variant is already locked in as an `int`.

Comment: @HariomSingh As a quick "workaround" you can add `char` to the variant type and then have overload the `operator()` for `char` and hive it throw an exception.

Comment: @NathanOliver smart...that's  one other way to do that ..thanks for proposing it .presently for time being I can do that ..may be later will try to explore std::visit

Comment: You have a very weird definition of "first".